# How to use "fuser" to get process list for nested folder while using with parent folder as argument?

Tags: bash, solaris

I am using `fuser` command to get the list of processes accessing a folder. However if the process is working on a file present in a inner folder, executing `fuser` command on the parent does not provide details of the process working on inner folder.

Is there any way I can pull the process details of the inner folders as well while executing `fuser` on the parent?

I am working with Solaris 5.8.

Below is the code which I tried:

```
~: pwd
/home/ah388

~: ls
sasuser.v91/

~: cd sasuser.v91/
~/sasuser.v91: cat kk.sh
while [ 1 ]; do
echo "" > /dev/null
done;

~/sasuser.v91: ./kk.sh &
[1] 15140

~/sasuser.v91: ls
a/      kk.sh*

~/sasuser.v91: cd a
~/sasuser.v91: ls
kk.sh*

~/sasuser.v91/a: ./kk.sh &
[2] 15271

~/sasuser.v91/a: cd

~: fuser -u sasuser.v91
sasuser.v91:    15140c(ah388880) --> What about 15271 Process

~: jobs
[1]-  Running                 ./kk.sh &  (wd: ~/sasuser.v91)
[2]+  Running                 ./kk.sh &  (wd: ~/sasuser.v91/a)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will show all directories currently used by users:

```
fuser -u $(find sasuser.v91 -type d) 2>&1 | grep 'c('
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create a script to perform that for you

```
for i in `find directory -type d`
do
 echo $i
 fuser -u $i
done
```

You can even add a if to see if there is some output and just print the ones with running processes.